# c++ issue with calculating data from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a beginning textbook c++ assignment. It is a basic calculation from an array that drops the highest and lowest scores. Every time I run it, I get 0 as the answer. I'm assuming the issue is in main or calculate score. I appreciate anyone who is willing to take a couple mins to look at this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printHeader(int judges);
void enterData (float scores[], int judges, float difficulty);
float calculateScore(float scores[], const int judges, float difficulty, int maxScore, int least);
int indexofLeast(float scores[], const int judges);
int indexofMax(float scores[], const int judges);

int main () {
    const int judges = 7;
    float scores [judges];
    float difficulty = 0;
    int maxScore = indexofMax(scores, judges);
    int least = indexofLeast(scores, judges);
    float finalscore = calculateScore(scores, judges, difficulty, maxScore, least);

    printHeader (judges);
    enterData (scores, judges, difficulty);  // get user input
    indexofLeast(scores, judges); // find lowest score 
    indexofMax(scores, judges); // find highest score
    calculateScore (scores, judges, difficulty, maxScore, least); // get final score
    cout << "The final score is " << finalscore << '\n';

    return 0;
}

void printHeader(const int judges) {
    cout << "This program calculates a divers score over" << judges << "judges" << endl;
}

void enterData(float scores[], const int judges, float difficulty) {
    for (int i = 0; i < judges; i++){
        cout <<"Enter score for judge " << i+1 << endl; 
        cin >> scores[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter difficulty: "<< endl;
    cin >> difficulty;
}

float calculateScore(float scores[], const int judges, float difficulty, int maxScore, int least) {
    float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < judges; i++) {
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return (sum - scores[least] - scores[maxScore]) * difficulty * 0.6;
}

int indexofLeast(float scores[], const int judges) {
    int least = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i< judges; i++) {
        if (scores[i] < scores[least])
            least = i;
    }
    return least;
}

int indexofMax(float scores[], const int judges) {
    int maxScore = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i< judges; i++) {
        if (scores[i] > scores[maxScore]) 
            maxScore = i; 
        }
    return  maxScore;
}
```

For expected input I entered 7 scores, (between 0 and 10): 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10
So drop highest and lowest 1 and 10. So sum = 21
Degree of difficulty between 1.2 and and 4.0: 3.0
So 21 * 3.0 * 0.6 = 37.8 for expected input/ output
I actually get -0

Comment: Could you please provide example input and expected ouput.

Comment: In `main()` you calculate `maxScore`, `least` and `finalscore` before you query for data. Then you call the functions again but discard their return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `difficulty` as a reference into `enterData`.

```
void enterData(float scores[], const int judges, float &difficulty)
                                                       ^
```

The problem is that you expect it to contain the value that the user entered.  You initialise it to zero, then call `enterData`.  But when that function returns, the value is still zero because the parameter was a local variable.  Later, you multiply your result by `difficulty`, so the result is always zero.

Using a reference to return the user-inputted value should fix your problem.  Syntactically, the only thing you need to change is to add the `&` to the function definition as I've shown.  You still call the function in the same way.

I urge you to develop the skills to critically analyse and test your code by yourself, rather than asking people.  If you thought the issue was in the score calculation, you could have easily displayed all the values that go into the score calculation, and worked backwards from there...  *ie "why is difficulty zero?  at what point does it become zero?"*

---

To address your issue in the comments, your code is doing stuff in the wrong order.  You need to  assign the return values *after* the user enters data:

```
const int judges = 7;
float scores [judges];
float difficulty = 0;

printHeader (judges);
enterData (scores, judges, difficulty);  // get user input

int maxScore = indexofMax(scores, judges);
int least = indexofLeast(scores, judges);
float finalscore = calculateScore(scores, judges, difficulty, maxScore, least);
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the & to the function definition. I still get -0 as the output

Comment: That is because you call and assign all your values during initialisation, *before* calling `enterData`. When you call them later, you do not actually assign the result.

Comment: paddy, thank you, I will take some time to read it and understand. I really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

because you set difficulty to zero:

```
    float difficulty = 0;
```

and then in the function you declear

```
 void enterData(float scores[], const int judges, float difficulty)
```

which mean you get it by value. so the value is not changing and you stay with zero.

you need to pass a refernce to difficulty:

```
 void enterData(float scores[], const int judges, float &difficulty)
```

Answer (score 2):

you are multiplying by difficulty which is never changed from being 0. If you want to change difficulty, change the prototype and definition of enterData to the following

```
void enterData(float scores[], const int judges, float &difficulty)
```

See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/ for a more detailed explanation of passing by reference.

Comment: Do I need to do the same in calculatescore?

Comment: @Marla: `calculateScore` doesn't attempt to change any of it's parameters, so it's not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on previous answers, I think you have fallen into a common error of understanding how '=' works in C/C++, often picked up from thinking of variables too much like algebra.

```
int maxScore = indexofMax(scores, judges);
```

This does not describe what "maxScore" is or will be, it assigns it a value. Consider
    #include

```
int f(int n);  // some mathematical function.

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
   int a = 1;
   int b = f(a);
   a = 15;
   std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

int f(int n) { return n * 2; } // f(n) = 2f
```

This program will print "2", not not "30".

```
int b = f(a);
// is equivalent to
int b;
b = f(a);
```

in both cases, `b` has been assigned a value, based on the evaluation of f(a) at the time. Changing 'a' beyond this point has no effect.